# How to add significance levels to a pre existing heatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation, p-value

I'm working with a dataset that has correlation measures.

I created a heatmap with this data and now I want to add p.values (which are stored in another dataset) to this heatmap, however I can´t seem to find a way to add in the form of * and ** from.

I created another matrix using the p-values (both in numeric and asterisk form) and used the function cellnote to add it to the heatmap. using this formula:

```
heatmap.2(data_mat,col=my_palette(n=20),trace = "none",Colv =NA,Rowv = NA, cexRow=1, cexCol=1,cellnote = dataE_mat)
```

My data being data_mat and dataE_mat the p-values but it added a bunch of 1,2,3,4 in the heatmap even in the areas where I left blank in the dataset.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.